# App get force stop run on lollipop version

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, nexus-5

I am an android beginner, I have developed one app, it was working kitkat version, but it's not supported in lollipop version (nexus 5). When I run the app in nexus 5 the app get force stop. This problem arrives development side or lollipop side Any one can help me

For your reference I have used android version as below

Min sdk is 14

Taget Sdk is 21

Comment: you need to post relevant details. Post the relevant code and the stacktrace

Comment: Its depends upon your code. What you have done?

Comment: Hi, I used the Facebook SDK for user can login using Facebook, App will force stop after login Facebook before home page display

Comment: This question is very low quality. Please learn the basics to debug an android app, i'm sure you can google many of these basics. Help US before we can help YOU.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of some libraries you have used.I got the same issue when I was having simonvtmenudrawer in my app which was not supported in lolipop.I replaced the same and it is now working fine.

Comment: Hi Karthika, I also use slide navigation drawer, but I don't have any library. I just have one class to slide navigation but I have used the Facebook SDK for user login thank you for your comment

Comment: Sorry I can run the app without connection of the system also I can't see the Log error

Comment: try logcat app from playstore and take the screenshot when you get a crash

Comment: Ok I will  try to get logcat error and take screenshot